# Get user info in boonex dolphin

Tags: boonex-dolphin

I am new to Boonex Dolphin and I want to get `user` `data` `(userid, username, avatar and link)` in javascript. How do I get this data in a javascript file? Are there any functions that provide the above data?

Answer (score 0):

Use `getProfileInfo();` method and passing inside parameter as **user id** thats it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default function to get the profile info from javascript

You've 2 options

1. Pass the ajax request to get the profile info
2. pass the userInfo into the JS page , before loading